# drf-spectacular: add response description

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How can I add description to responses in the @extend_schema decorator?

```
'500':
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
      description: ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that specific description location you are referring to is not easily available through the decorators. however, there are multiple places a description can be put.

1. `@extend_schema(description='Your description')` this will add the description to the view action (operation). However, this is targeted to the operation itself and not the `500` Error case.
2. adding a docstring to your `Error` serializer. probably what you want to do.

this part is still a bit rough as the "Error" feature is still work in progress.

Comment: I am using the same serializer for multiple error codes (4XX, 500)

Comment: this may seem like a basic feature, but is trickier than it looks. sry to say that this is currently not supported.

Comment: Any Fixes till now?

Comment: There is now OpenApiResponse to wrap the Serializer together with a description string. The feature was added in the latest 0.15.0 release.

Comment: Hi @Insa, could you give a rough example/pointer how to add a docstring to the Error serializer; I am not sure where I can find or override these (e.g. serializers.ValidationError is an Exception subclass). Second, I'd be grateful if you could also detailed a bit more how the OpenAPiResponse could be helpful here. The docs (https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html?highlight=openapiresponse#drf_spectacular.utils.OpenApiResponse) didn't make me much wiser

Comment: @Rabarberski, have a look [at the tests](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/1f7cf5d8342f5ed3f619afcf92fb43e3b4ff26cb/tests/test_regressions.py#L1744) for usage. you simply wrap what you would have put into `extend_schema(responses=XXX)`. Regarding the docstring, i literally meant a triple-quoted docstring on the class, which gets picked up just fine.

Comment: Hi @Insa. Thanks, test link got me going. My question on docstring was perhaps confusing; I know what a docstirng is :-) but I don't know how to override the Error serializer (where to import it from?).

Comment: now i get it. we do not support "error serializers" (APIException) yet. it is on the roadmap though. Best you can do atm is write a regular serializer that mocks the error response for annotation.

Answer (score 10):

Insa's answer and comments led me to a working solution using `OpenApiResponse` (requires drf-spectacular version >=0.15)

Here's some example code of how I did it:

```
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema, OpenApiResponse
from rest_framework import generics

class MyResourceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    @extend_schema(
        summary="Create a new resource",
        responses={
            201: OpenApiResponse(response=MyCustomSerializer,
                                 description='Created. New resource in response'),
            400: OpenApiResponse(description='Bad request (something invalid)'),
        },
    )
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ 
        Some explanation goes here ...
        """
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

- The documentation on OpenApiResponse is here: https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html?highlight=openapiresponse#drf_spectacular.utils.OpenApiResponse
- But the tests are actually more useful: https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/1f7cf5d8342f5ed3f619afcf92fb43e3b4ff26cb/tests/test_regressions.py#L1744

Comment: the docs are there to explain what is possible/expected. it would be impossible to show all cases in the doc. the test are explicitly written as a library of examples, i.e. short, concise, isolated. the majority of use cases can be found in the tests.